# How to create an attribute in ASP.NET MVC that checks if session var is available?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session-variables

I need to create a custom controller attribute in asp.net that will check if a specific session var is set. This is not for authentication. If the var is not set, then I need to redirect to a different view.

```
public class CheckPatientSetAttribute : Attribute
{
    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.HttpContext.Session["Patient"] == null)
        {
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Redirect("/");
        }
    }
}
```

Should an attribute be used in this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

I think its an overkill to use attribute in this scenario. It will work, don't get me wrong, its just not really decoration nor attribute of certain property of some model, but rather piece of business logic that belongs to business logic layer. 
If this piece is repeating few times, externalize it to separate method or class, based on utility and ease for others to understand. I think `Attribute` doesn't makes it easy to understand, but actually more misleading than useful. IMHO.

As usual, there's no right answer to your question, all based on utility, usability and ease of understanding later on (maintenance).